# Preflight request error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource for Elastic Search

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I want to invoke an elastic search web service from Angular JS. When I am calling it like below:

```
$http.post('http://[IP]:9200/providers3/provider3/_search',JSON.stringify(objToSend)).success(function(){

            console.log('Data sent successfully!!');

        });
```

I am getting this error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://[IP]:9200/providers3/provider3/_search. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin "http://localhost:8085" is therefore not allowed access.`

I made changes in elasticsearch.yml file as below:

```
http.cors.enabled : true // 
http.cors.allow-origin: "/.*/"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers : "X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"*
```

But after adding these lines to .yml file,  Elastic search server fails to start.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: have you added CROS support?

Comment: Search CORS in angularjs you will get lots of results. You question belongs to that only.

Comment: @micronyks Did you even read the question? CORS is a server side issue and has nothing to do with angular at all

Comment: After reading some posts tried solutions given here http://www.code-sample.com/2015/02/enabling-cors-in-angularjs.html. No luck still. What else should I try?

Answer (score 0):

What if you change allow-origin to "*" instead of your current regex? It should work, I had the same issue.

Comment: Its working now. Thanks everyone. it was just related to yml formatting, I was missing 1 space so it wasn't working. Thanks everyone.